# Is there a way to view a UI Button's Object ID in Swift? Button created programmatically

Tags: swift, user-interface

I have created a UI button programmatically here and in order to localize the button's title I need the Object Id. However, since this button was not created through story board or Swift UI, I cannot use the identifier helper. Is there any way to access the object id? Thank you

```
playButton.frame = CGRect (x:frame.midX - 70, y:frame.midY - 110, width: 140, height: 50)
        playButton.setTitle("bear", for: UIControl.State.normal)
        playButton.setTitleColor(UIColor.white, for: .normal)
        playButton.backgroundColor = .clear
        playButton.layer.cornerRadius = 10
        playButton.layer.borderWidth = 2
        playButton.layer.borderColor=UIColor.white.cgColor
        playButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(playGame), for: UIControl.Event.touchUpInside)
        playButton.titleLabel!.font = UIFont(name: "Press Start 2P", size: 20)
        playButton.titleLabel!.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.center
        playButton.backgroundColor = customGreen
        self.view!.addSubview(playButton)
```

Comment: Object ID...  Is that a tag number?  Why don't you use `accessibilityIdentifier`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need object id for localizing UIKit components created programmatically. You can do it with `NSLocalizedString`. Remmember to add `Localizable.strings` file with `"bear" = "<localization for bear>";` for all the language your app supports. And use it like this:

```
let title = NSLocalizedString("bear", comment: "My comment")
playButton.setTitle(title, for: UIControl.State.normal)
```